# Flutter device daemon #2 exited (exit code 1)

Tags: flutter, git

I opened a zip file I downloaded, and when I try to run pub get, or any flutter command, the IDE gives me a flutter device daemon :
`Flutter device daemon #2 exited (exit code 1), stderr: Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project. The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly; to install Flutter, see the instructions at: https://flutter.dev/get-started`

Attempts I've tried(none worked):

1. I showed all the hidden files in the folder, including the git file.
2. I uploaded the project to github, and pushed everything to a repo